# Why is the prepareForSegue not working

Tags: ios, swift

I have a collection view with all the users in my parse database, and each cell has a unique label and image. When that cell is clicked I want the label and image to show up in an expanded view in another view controller. That view controller is placed inside a scroll view. The view controller is correctly placed in the scroll view. I am receiving and error: http://puu.sh/kZaRf/3a212b4063.png  Below is my code

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: friendcellView = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("friendcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! friendcellView

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }


    cell.friendname.text = arrayOfFriendsNames[indexPath.row]
    cell.friendpic.image =  arrayOfFriends[indexPath.row]
    //cell.friendpic.image = UIImage(named: arrayOfFriendsTest[indexPath.row])
    cell.friendpic.layer.cornerRadius = cell.friendpic.frame.size.width/2;
    cell.friendpic.clipsToBounds = true
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("friendaccess", sender: self)

    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("Cell \(indexPath.row) selected")
    print(arrayOfFriendsNames[indexPath.row])
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("friendaccess", sender: self)
}

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "friendaccess"){
       (segue.destinationViewController as! FriendProfile).friendname == (sender as! friendcellView).friendname.text
        (segue.destinationViewController as! FriendProfile).friendimage == (sender as! friendcellView).friendpic.image
    }
}
```

Below is the code for the FriendProfile

```
class FriendProfile: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var friendimage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var friendname: UILabel!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    friendimage.layer.cornerRadius = self.friendimage.frame.size.width / 2;
    friendimage.clipsToBounds = true



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by the error, you are trying to cast `segue.destinationViewController` to `FriendProfile` when it actually an instance of `FriendProfilePages`.

You are either casting to the wrong type, or you set the wrong type for your view controller in your storyboard.  Based on the code above, I'm guessing it's probably the latter issue.

Select the view controller at the root of the scene that is the destination of the segue with the identifier `friendaccess`, open the identity inspector (command-option-3), and change the value in the Custom Class field from `FriendProfilePages` to `FriendProfile`.

Also, the following lines of code are doing an equality check on the IBOutlets of the view controller.  I doubt this is what you want.  You probably want assignment statements instead (although at this point in the view controller life cycle, the views connected to the outlets won't have been created yet).

```
(segue.destinationViewController as! FriendProfile).friendname == (sender as! friendcellView).friendname.text
(segue.destinationViewController as! FriendProfile).friendimage == (sender as! friendcellView).friendpic.image
```

Comment: I mean you're casting `segue.destinationViewController` to a `FriendProfile` instance, and it is not one, so the app crashes.  If you think it should be a `FriendProfile` instance and not a `FriendProfilePages` instance, you can change it in the storyboard.  Select the view controller at the root of the scene that is the destination of the segue, open the identity inspector (command-option-3), and change the value in the Custom Class field from `FriendProfile` to `FriendProfilePages`.